# Resize DIV to maximum height in table

Tags: html, css

i have such code:

```
<td width="10">
<div style="border-left: 1px dashed #cccccc;width:10px;height:100%;"></div>
</td>
```

and i have other two columns with elements, which may be big in height
i want to set div dinamically to maximum height as in bigest column. height:100% does not work.
How to do that?

Comment: You can do this through jQuery.

Comment: How about not assigning any height?

Comment: I suppose there is no way to do this with css

Comment: don't use inline styles, link to a stylesheet. The Width attribute on TD elements is obsolete as of HTML5

Comment: 2Pawan: any height does not work
2Billy: this is not final code

Comment: Can you provide pls any image for better understanding of your problem?

Comment: i just use <td width="10" background="spacer.gif"></td> with Photoshoped "1px dashed #cccccc" 10x6px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not do it using pure html/css. But I've got it to work with a few lines of **javascript code**:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var h  = document.getElementById('maintable').offsetHeight;
    var el = document.getElementById('resizeme');
    el.style.height = h+'px';
}
```

**html**:

```
<table id="maintable">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><div id="resizeme"></div></td>
        <td>one<br/>two<br/>three<br/>four<br/>five<br/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**:

```
#resizeme {border: 1px solid blue;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table tr td {vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;}
```

Basically, all depends of what is your final goal. Probably you could solve your problem using only html/css...
Also, try not to use css styles in your html code...

Answer (score 0):

```
<td width="10px">
<div style="border-left: 1px dashed #cccccc;width:inherit;display:table"></div>
</td>
```

hope this helps